# Sharepoint 2010 query service throws"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wrote a custum c# code that consumes Sharepoint 2010 QueryEx webservice.

The code runs fine in most places.

When the code is running in one of my clients server the webservice returns the following error:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->  Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

The sharepoint website is not using annonymus ahuthentication.

I set the account which is running the code as the content access account in sharepoint - but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but the issue I had might relate to your problem...

[Sharepoint 2010 search via webservice gives "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098738/sharepoint-2010-search-via-webservice-gives-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorize)